# How did the Romans say "bad news"?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

I would like to have an idiomatic way to say "good news" and "bad news" in Latin.
For example, I would like to be able to say "I have some good news" or "The bad news is that you need an operation".
I found *boni nuntii* in [Cicero's *Ad Atticum* 3.XI.1](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/att3.shtml#11), and context suggests it means what I want.
(The same phrase appears also in the [Second Book of Kings](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bible/kings2.shtml#7), but it is in singular genitive.)
However, I have been unable to locate a similar expression for bad news.

Are there attested examples in classical literature of something that means "bad news" in a way similar to how *boni nuntii* means "good news"?
I believe *mali nuntii* (which I didn't find) would be understood perfectly, but I wonder if I'm missing an idiom here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found [Cic. Agr. 2.30](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0013:text=Agr.:speech=2:chapter=30&highlight=malum%2Cmalus%2Cnuntium%2Cnuntius), using the compound *malus nuntius* twice.

I am concerned, however, that this might not necessarily be the right answer: Just finding one example or two of something does not imply it is *the* way a Roman would have said it. Maybe they just used some other expression (not invoving *nuntii* at all) that sounded better to them (what about *fabula*, *rumor*? What if one of these has an intrinsic bad connotation?). I remember a professor of mine (he was a PhD in AI) using a very strange word/spelling, claiming it was right just because he googled it and there were results.

Pity that [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/?moreLanguages=1#moreLanguages) doesn't have Latin among its alternatives.

**Edit:** Apparently, Cicero also uses [tristis fama](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0011:text=Phil.:speech=14:chapter=6) to mean bad news (according to [translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0021:speech=14:chapter=6&highlight=news%2Cbad), bad meaning *sad* here, of course).

Comment: In that context (and in general) *fama* sounds more like "rumor" than "news". But I do like the phrase nevertheless. I actually begin to like the expression *tristis nuntius* quite a bit, attested or not.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I suppose that depends on what you mean by "news". Rumors often get reported on by the "news", but the Romans didn't have "news" in the same way we moderns do.