# About "joyful news"

Tags: vocabulary

I see there's a word for it: [**laetificum, laetificī**](http://latinlexicon.org/search_english.php).

Then, if there's a Latin word for "joyful news," is there also a Latin word for "sad news"?

Comment: There is a related older question about [bad news](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/982/79).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Laetificus* is a compound of *laetus* "happy" and *faciō* "make". (*Fac-* turns into *fic-* when something comes before it, due to stress rules in early Latin.) [L&S lists it as an adjective](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlaetificus) meaning "gladdening". When this adjective is used as a substantive in the neuter plural, "gladdening things", it means "good news". (Note that this tends to be plural *laetifica, -ōrum*, not singular.)

While I don't believe this is attested, you could make a similar compound with *tristis* "sad": *tristifica, -ōrum* "saddening things, sad news". This would be easily understandable to a Latin speaker even if the form isn't attested.

Alternately, *tristis* can mean "saddening" as well as "sad", so you could use it substantively: *tristia, -um*. Ovid called the poems he wrote in exile *tristia*, "sad things" or "saddening things".